# Doesn't hazelcast jet streaming need serializer desrializer like kafka streaming

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, hazelcast-jet

We are doing poc on kafka vs jet streaming, i noticed that kafka need serializer and desrializer, but didn't see it in jet streaming so was just wondering how does jet sends data between the clusters and to the client.

Also what are the pros and cons of using one over the other.

Please note that we are only comparing streaming part not the part that kafka is fully fault tolerant but jet is not as its all in memory in jet.

We need to find pros and cons more on streaming part.

Answer (score 0):

Jet natively supports the default Java serialization, so if you don't configure anything and your data items are `Serializable`, it will work. Java serialization, however, has large overheads and if your pipeline has a lot of traffic, this can easily become the bottleneck. In that case you can implement Hazelcast serialization for your objects, as described in the [Jet reference manual](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.7.2/manual/#standard-java-serialization-is-slow), for example:

```
SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig()
        .setImplementation(new MyItemSerializer())
        .setTypeClass(MyItem.class);
JetConfig config = new JetConfig();
    config.getHazelcastConfig().getSerializationConfig()
          .addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);
JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(config);
```

Jet's primary advantage over Kafka Streams is performance because it's in-memory.

Just like Hazelcast IMDG, Hazelcast Jet is tolerant to the failure of a configured number of cluster members. It supports the *exactly once* and *at least once* processing guarantees. Jet Enterprise Edition supports the storing of of the processing state to durable storage.

Comment: When we enable durable storage in that case also will it be better in performance compared to kafka as jet will also saving to disk like kafka?

Comment: You can't get around the throughput limitations of the storage, but where Kafka stores all the stream items, Jet stores just the state of the operators. To achieve end-to-end _exactly once_ you do need to store the items at the input (so you can replay them after a failure), but not within the pipeline.

Comment: So if jet doesnt store all the elements then in case of cluster down i will loose data unlike kafka does, and to achieve complete fault tolerance in jet i will have to explicitly store them in hbase or some other db or file, is that right (even in case of enterprise edition ) ?

Comment: Hazelcast Jet is fault-tolerant (FT) on its own, but to achieve end-to-end FT, you need an FT data source, able to replay the recent data when asked. On the sink side you need either a transactional sink or one that can de-duplicate the data it receives. A Jet cluster with Hot Restart enabled can be completely shut down and then restarted with no data loss.